# transformer.transform() in javax.xml.transform never returns- How to time out such request

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml transformation and using ransformer.transform() method to do the transformation. My src has some really heavy data and this method basically never returns. Is there a way to timeout this request in the API.

Comment: You have an XML transformation such as what? Operating on what? From what source? Unless it's reading from a network you don't want to timeout at all, you want to speed it up so it doesn't appear to run forever.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: no.

If you run the whole thing under an application server such as WebSphere or JBoss then you may find there are facilities at that level that can help you.

Or as a DIY solution you could try running the transformation in a separate thread, and interrupting the thread.

The problem though is that you may be in a busy CPU loop that doesn't stop to ask if it's been interrupted.